# Meteor AutoForm set optional field to be required

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I've the following (simplified) SimpleSchema:

```
EventSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    eventType: {
        type: String
    },
    kicker: {
        type: String
    },
    kicker2: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    }
});
```

With this I'm using AutoForm to generate a insert form. Here is a simplified version of it:

```
{{#autoForm schema="EventSchema" type="method" meteormethod="addEvent"}}
    {{> afFieldInput name="eventType" options=getSubstitutionEventTypes type="select-radio-inline"}}

    {{> afFieldInput name="kicker" type="select" options=this}}

    {{> afFieldInput name="kicker2" type="select" options=this}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

As I'm using this Schema in an other autoForm where I don't have to input "kicker2", I've set this field to be optional. But in the form mentioned above, this field is required too. So how can I override the optional setting for a field in a specific form?

I've already tried the following, but it didn't work (required isn't rendered in the HTML):

```
{{> afFieldInput name="kicker2" type="select" options=this required="required"}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set the `schema` attribute for the form to a SimpleSchema instance that matches the validation you want for the form. Source [What is the best way to set field optional on autoform validation and required on insert (method & collection2)](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/238)

Answer (score 1):

You have some tricks to have an optional value depending on situations, a nice one would be to set the optional value on the return of a function, giving something like this:

```
EventSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    eventType: {
        type: String
    },
    kicker: {
        type: String
    },
    kicker2: {
        type: String,
        optional: function() {
            return (! this.isInsert)
        }
    }
});
```

So it is optional on update but not on insert (you can use whatever means to customize it).
Another way to have different validation rules between forms is simply by creating a specific schema for a given form and then having `autoForm(schema=yourSpecificSchema ...` instead of `autoForm(collection="Meteor.users"`. Do not forget to register an helper so your schema is accessible from your form. You can refer on the official documentation for more details: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#non-collection-forms

Comment: using a function for "optional" doesn't work for me, it seems, that there are only boolean values allowed. I've fixed my problem by "overriding" my Schema, so I created a second Schema with the following code:
EventSchema = new SimpleSchema([EventSchema, {
    kicker2: {
        type: String,
        optional: false
    }
}]);

Comment: Good, I'd say that the safest solution in your case. Also, I don't understand why the optional: function() {} thing didn't work. I had some issues with coffeescript but as long as you keep it the JS way, you shouldn't have any trouble. If you still have some output of the error, this would be cool. Also, if you found your solution, do not forget to accept it (it can be edited to fit perfectly to the question).

Comment: The thing is, if "kicker2" is optional depends on the value of "eventType". In the optional function I tried using "this.field('eventType').value" to check the selected value, but this didn't work as this function seems not to be available (in comparison to autovalue). As I display the options for eventType, where optional should always be false in this form, using a derived Schema works fine. In the other form (where optional should always be true), I'm using the original Schema.

Comment: Yes, as the _optional_ option in Simple Schema is fired before _autovalue_ which populates a field after it's been successfully submitted (and validated), not all _autovalue_'s attributes are accessible from _optional_.