# How to dynamically change the value of an optional attribute of a field in Autoform / SimpleSchema?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I have a SimpleSchema instance with two fields:

```
 isApproved: {
    type: Boolean,
    defaultValue: false
  },
  impactedSystems: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  }
```

I'd like to change the `optional` attribute of *impactedSystems* to `false` if *isApproved* is set to `true`.

I've tried following the instructions in the [docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/blob/master/DOCS.md#make-a-field-conditionally-required) but I can't get it to work. It suggests I add a custom function to *impactedSystems* like so (modified with my field names):

```
custom: function () {
  var shouldBeRequired = this.field('isApproved').value == 1;

  if (shouldBeRequired) {
    // inserts
    if (!this.operator) {
      if (!this.isSet || this.value === null || this.value === "") return "required";
    }

    // updates
    else if (this.isSet) {
      if (this.operator === "$set" && this.value === null || this.value === "") return "required";
      if (this.operator === "$unset") return "required";
      if (this.operator === "$rename") return "required";
    }
  }
}
```

The field stays optional whether *isApproved* is true or not.

I also tried the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112599/meteor-autoform-set-optional-field-to-be-required) answer but the value of `optional` doesn't change when the field it depends on (`isApproved`) is updated.

How can I have the value of `optional` become the opposite of another boolean type field?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I was inserting *isApproved* from one form and then updating *impactedSystems* in another. All I had to do was include *isApproved* (with `type=hidden`) in the update form where I want its value to be read. The code I provided is correct.

**Example**

```
{#autoForm collection=Requests doc=this id="singleRequestLayout" type="update"}} //This can also be of type insert
    {{> afQuickField name="isApproved" type="hidden"}}
    {{> afQuickField name="impactedSystems"}}

    <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. it is admittedly a little convoluted...

This is a generic helper you can use across all your schemas:

```
 // This helper method does the ceremony around SimpleSchema's requirements

export const isRequired = (thing,shouldBeRequired) => {
  if (shouldBeRequired) {
    // inserts
    if (!thing.operator) {
      if (!thing.isSet || thing.value === null || thing.value === "") return "required";
    }

    // updates
    else if (thing.isSet) {
      if (thing.operator === "$set" && thing.value === null || thing.value === "") return "required";
      if (thing.operator === "$unset") return "required";
      if (thing.operator === "$rename") return "required";
    }
  }
};
```

In the schema itself you can do it like this:

```
const isRequiredWhenApproved = (record) => {
  const shouldBeRequired = (record.field('isApproved').value);
  return isRequired(record, shouldBeRequired);
};

  isApproved: {
    type: Boolean,
    defaultValue: false
  },
  impactedSystems: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    custom() {
      return isRequiredWhenApproved(this);
    },
  },
```

I hope that works for you

Comment: Thanks! The code I provided turned out to be correct as well. I had the two fields in two different forms causing one (on each form) to be undefined.