# Simple-schema conditionally required field within array of objects

Tags: javascript, meteor, simple-schema

I'm trying to make a field conditionally required, however, I'm having trouble accessing the field value when it's within an array of objects. `this.field` returns undefined. Basically what I want to do is check if the `classes.$.active` field is false. If it is false I want the `monday` field to set to false. If I can successfully check the value of `active` I can do the rest.

```
classes: {
  type: Array,
  optional: true,
},
'classes.$': {
  type: Object,
  optional: true,
},
'classes.$.monday': {
  type: Boolean,
  optional: true,
  custom() {
    console.log('test', this.field('classes.$.active').value);
  },
}
```

Comment: Is it used together with AutoForm?

Comment: No it's not used with autoform

Comment: I think this answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535803/how-to-dynamically-change-the-value-of-an-optional-attribute-of-a-field-in-autof/51538073#51538073